# ckFinde .netcore: It was not possible to load the XML response from the web server. The server returned an empty response

Tags: c#, xml, ckeditor, asp.net-core-mvc, ckfinder

I am using Ck Editor and Ck Finder in my Dot Net Core project but when i try to browse server in Ck Finder I am facing the error: "It was not possible to load the XML response from the web server. The server returned an empty response".

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture http packets which usually would give more information about failure.  Two things to check 1) Headers to see what modes were used for transfer 2) Status in response to see if you are getting 200 Done, 100 Continue, or an error usually in the 400 to 500 range.

Comment: I haven't used "Finder" but it sounds like it needs some server side component. Is that installed/configured correctly?

Comment: yes hans i think it is intalled correctly but when i open inspect element on ckfinder, in the console tab i have an error from it's connector

Comment: Remove content not directly related to question.